# UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForETH not working

Tags: solidity

I have been trying to make a swap using UniSwapV2 at Kovan Testnet, but it seems to keep failing. Does anyone knows what is wrong with my piece of code?

```
function uniswapSwap(uint256 daiAmount) public payable {
    // convert to Wei
    uint256 amountIn = daiAmount;
    //require(DAI.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn), 'transferFrom failed.'); 
    address kovanDAI = address(0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa);
    IERC20 DAI= IERC20(kovanDAI);
    address uniswapRouterAddress = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    
    IUniswapV2Router02 uniswapRouter2 = IUniswapV2Router02(uniswapRouterAddress);
    
    require(DAI.approve(address(uniswapRouter2), amountIn), 'approve failed.');
    
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(DAI);
    path[1] = uniswapRouter2.WETH();
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15;
    uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(daiAmount, 0, path, address(this), deadline);
    //emit GetDestAmount(amounts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Why did you set this function `payable`?! Also increase deadline to `block.timestamp + 150`, 15 sec is not enough

Comment: When you say “failing”, can you offer more detail? Is there an error or logging detail?